# What are the correct (convention) TYPO3 language fields?

Tags: typo3

can someone clarify what the correct, conventional fields are, for language-fields in TYPO3?

I See all kinds of this for example:

```php
l10n_parent
i10n_parent
l18n_parent
i18n_parent

... same for the other l10n_ fields
```

Now the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/12.4/en-us/BestPractises/LanguageFields.html) (TYPO3 12.4) says "...It is possible to change the names (...), however this is strongly discouraged as it breaks convention(...)"

Then the docs explains the fields `sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_source, l10n_diffsource`.
Some note says "*Sometimes **l18n_diffsource** is used for (...) historic reasons*"

Then there is [this](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/12.4/en-us/BestPractises/LanguageFields.html#example-enable-table-for-localization-and-translation) example, that completely confuses me. There is a column for `l18n_parent` and the (historic?) `l18n_diffsource`.
Shouldn't both start with `l10n_`?

Another thing is te `l18n` itself (with an lowercase "L"). If this should be the numeronym for "Internationalisation", shouldn't the fields are named with `i18n_...`?
I think the writer of this part of the docs confused the l18n (lower L) and I18n (capital i), which looks the same in most fonts, and the case that l10n is actually correct with a lower "L".

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are right that `l18n_parent` is an error in the `tt_content` table. It is likely caused by a confusion of l10n and i18n. This still exists for historic reasons and the expected amount of work would be huge to fix this to `i18n_parent` as used in all other tables. That is why it still exists like this today.

Comment: Actually it's l10n_parent with a lowercase L in all other tables than the historic ones.

Comment: So, what would be the correct convention? l10n_parent?

Comment: See also https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100031 (issue was closed). Not sure why it's such a huge task, since the field names are configurable.

Comment: see also docs page, where the fields are explained: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/BestPractises/LanguageFields.html